# Allow element with Overflow-X to be grabbed and dragged with a mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

So, I have a scrollable div using `overflow-x` to scroll, and I've hid the scrollbar. Now I need to find a way for a touchpad or mouse to be able to scroll the `div`. It only scrolls when using a touchscreen or on mobile devices, which I've tested using DevTools.

```css
:root{
  --primary:#0a2a6d;
  --black:#000c27;
  --white:#ffffff;
  --grey:#d9d9d9;
  --dark:#8a8a8a;
}
.product{
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  width:275px;
  margin-left:0.7%;
  margin-right:0.7%;
  text-align:left;
  /* margin:auto; */
  height:365px;
  border:var(--grey) 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
}
.info{
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin:0;
  color:var(--black);
  margin-top:2px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
.rating{
 position: relative;
 left:-75px;
 top:-10px;
 transform: scale(0.4);
}
.product-list{
  user-select: none;
  margin-left:0.7%;
  margin-right:0.7%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.product-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display:none;
}
.img{
  width:300px;
  height:222px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.product span{
  font-size:20px;
}h5{
  font-weight:500;
  font-size:20px;
  margin:0;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list">
    <div class="product">
      <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false">
        <h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating">
          <use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use>
              <use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use>
              <use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use>
          <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use>
              <use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use>
              <use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>
        </svg>   
        <p class="info"><span>Rented for <b>3</b> days</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div><div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div><div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div><div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div><div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div><div class="product"><img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/diy-wedding-decorations-1582647454.jpg?crop=0.670xw:1.00xh;0.221xw,0&amp;resize=640:*" class="img" draggable="false"><h5>Flower Centerpiece</h5><svg viewBox="0 0 102 18" class="rating"><use xlink:href="#stars-star" fill="#dc143c"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(21)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-star" transform="translate(42)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-half-star" transform="translate(63)"></use><use xlink:href="#stars-full-star" transform="translate(84)"></use>/svg&gt;</svg><p class="info">16<sup>99</sup><span> per day</span></p></div></div>
```

How would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an additonal transparent div where normaly the scrollbar would be.
When hovering over it (or the scrollbar) the scrollbar is visible.
When not hovering over one of them the scrollbar is invisible.

You could also make this feature dektop only with [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)